# Write a function which takes the tracking code as input. Look the tracking code up in the JSON then return the tracking code as output

Tags: json, ruby

I have a JSON file called "tracking.json".

```
[
{
    "tracking_number": "IN175417577",
    "status": "IN_TRANSIT",
    "address": "237 Pentonville Road, N1 9NG"
},
    {
    "tracking_number": "IN175417578",
    "status": "NOT_DISPATCHED",
    "address": "Holly House, Dale Road, Coalbrookdale, TF8 7DT"
},
    {
    "tracking_number": "IN175417579",
    "status": "DELIVERED",
    "address": "Number 10 Downing Street, London, SW1A 2AA"
}
]
```

I wrote a function that reads this in my app.rb file:

```
def compare_content(tracking_number)
 json_string = File.read("pages/tracking.json")
 # Uses the JSON module to create an array from the JSON string
 array_from_json = JSON.parse(json_string)
 # Iterates through the array of hashes
 array_from_json.each do |tracking_hash|
  if tracking_number == tracking_hash["tracking_number"]
    print "Package on its way"
 else
  print "Tracking Number does not exist"
    end
  end
end
```

The route to the pages is:

```
get "/:tracking_number/status" do
@tracking_number = params[:tracking_number]
compare_content(@tracking_number)
erb :status
end
```

The erb :status page is:

```
<h1>Status Pages: <%= @tracking_number %></h1>

<div>
   <h3>Package is on its way</h3>
</div>

<a href="/"> Back to Index</a>
```

How do I show the status if the package matches the tracking number?  Plus, if it doesn't how would I show that nothing matches?

Comment: Please try to come up with a better title for the question that _isn't_ the requirement for the lesson you're doing. I'd recommend practicing consistent indentation of your code. It'll help you debug and remember what your code does in the future. "[ask]", "[mcve]" and their linked pages are useful to read.

Comment: Will take note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be reduced to something like:

```
require 'json'

JSON_DATA = JSON[<<EOT]
[
  {
    "tracking_number": "IN175417577",
    "status": "IN_TRANSIT",
    "address": "237 Pentonville Road, N1 9NG"
  },
  {
    "tracking_number": "IN175417578",
    "status": "NOT_DISPATCHED",
    "address": "Holly House, Dale Road, Coalbrookdale, TF8 7DT"
  },
  {
    "tracking_number": "IN175417579",
    "status": "DELIVERED",
    "address": "Number 10 Downing Street, London, SW1A 2AA"
  }
]
EOT

def compare_content(tracking_number)
  msg = if JSON_DATA.any? { |h| tracking_number == h['tracking_number'] }
          "Package on its way"
        else
          "Tracking Number does not exist"
        end
  puts msg
end

compare_content('IN175417577')
compare_content('IN175417560')

# >> Package on its way
# >> Tracking Number does not exist
```

You probably need to account for the `status` field to show whether the package is actually in transit.

Note, we seldom use `print` in Ruby. `puts` is smarter and knows when to add a trailing "\n". `print` never adds a trailing newline, so you're forced to do so explicitly. That is occasionally a good thing but grab `puts` usually, and keep `print` in your back pocket for those rare occasions you need it.

Comment: Will try that the Tin Man.  Thanks for all your help J.D. and the Tin Man.

Comment: It's not necessary, or desirable, to thank people for help. Upvoting correct answers and selecting the one that solved the problem is how you show appreciation.

Comment: Just being polite.  Will uproot if the solution is correct.

Comment: It's important to understand that SO isn't a discussion list, it's a reference site. Politeness is nice, but the comment box specifically says `"Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”."` [meta] has lots of discussions about this, but it boils down to respect for others is important but we don't say "Hi", "Thanks" or  add signatures any more than you'd see those in a dictionary, cookbook or encyclopedia. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers